# Why is inverse multiplication shown as commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, inverse

Can someone explain why this is shown as commutative when matrix multiplication is not?
Is this a specific case with inverses?

"A square $(n\times n)$ matrix $A$ is said to have an inverse $A^{-1}$ iff $(A\times A^{-1})=(A^{-1}\times A)=I$.
In this case, the matrix $A$ is called invertible."

I thought at first it may be because it is a square, but I cannot render why square would be different.
If it is because it is square, then all inverses are square matrices, so then, are all inverse relations commutative?

Comment: Yes, for square matrices if you know that $AB=I$ then you immediately know that $BA=I$.

Comment: Not all matrix multiplications commute. Also, we have the notion of "left inverse" and "right inverse" when we look at group structure.

Comment: Here is a very good [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i/3895#3895).

Comment: Inverse of a matrix is defined for square matrix only.

Comment: Such commutativity is by *hypothesis*, i.e. that's [the *definition*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/486939/242) of a **two-sided** inverse (vs. one-sided, i.e. left or right inverse). Often "two sided" is ommitted, i.e. "inverse" means "two-sided inverse".

Comment: It's [easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15854/242) that if both a left and right inverse exist then they must be equal. But generally $\,AB=1\Rightarrow BA=1\,$ fails, [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252/242) let $B$ be a shift map $\,(v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots\,)\to(0,v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots\,)\,$ on a *infinite* dimension vector space.

Answer (score 3):

The definition quoted

$(*)\quad$if $A B=B A=I$, then $B$ is called an **inverse** of $A$

In that definition, we postulate that multiplication in both orders yields $I$.  So (as far as the definition is concerned) if $BA=I$ it could happen that $AB \ne I$, and then $B$ would not be "an inverse of $A$".

As some of the comments have indicated, in fact for square matrices, from $AB=I$ we may deduce $BA=I$.  So definition $(*)$ is stronger than needed.   But in some other similar settings (but not square matrices) we can, indeed have $BA=I$ but $AB \ne I$.  So it is perhaps educational to include the extra condition of $(*)$ even in this case.